# How to migrate syslog from log4j to log4j2

Tags: java, log4j

I am migrating from log4j to log4j2. How should I rewrite this configuration:

```
log4j.appender.SYSLOG=org.apache.log4j.net.SyslogAppender
log4j.appender.SYSLOG.Threshold=INFO
log4j.appender.SYSLOG.Header=false
log4j.appender.SYSLOG.syslogHost=localhost
log4j.appender.SYSLOG.layout=my.log.PatternLayoutNoStackTrace // Override PatternLayout where ignoresThrowable is set to false
log4j.appender.SYSLOG.layout.ConversionPattern=${log.app} %d{ISO8601} %-5p [%t] %-15c : %m%n
```

I tried something like this:

```
<Syslog name="syslog" host="localhost" port="514" protocol="UDP">
    <PatternLayout pattern="${log.app} %d{ISO8601} %-5p [%t] %-15c : %m%n%throwable{0}"/>
    <ThresholdFilter level="INFO" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY" />
</Syslog>
```

but this throws error: `Syslog has no parameter that matches element PatternLayout`

Is there a way how to change format in log4j2 syslog ?

Comment: Have you resolved this problem?

Comment: This might be helpful for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17947611/log4j2-syslog-appender-and-patternlayout